# Transpose & Repeat multiple columns & rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, data-analysis, transpose

I have the following data that im attempting to duplicate and transpose but im having issues with doing that.
Transpose doesnt seem to quite get me there.

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE | Column..BM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FruitOne | FruitTwo | FruitThree | 2000 | 2001 | ...2022 |
| Apples | Bananas | Grapes | RandomValueOne | RandomValueTwo | ...RandomValueN |

But I want the data to look like to following.

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FruitOne | FruitTwo | FruitThree | Year | Value |
| Apples | Bananas | Grapes | 2000 | RandomValueOne |
| Apples | Bananas | Grapes | 2001 | RandomValueTwo |
| Apples | Bananas | Grapes | ...2022 | ... RandomValueN |

Thanks for any assistance in this. I dont have access to R, MatLab, SPSS or anything like that. Hoping to achieve this in excel.

Thanks.

Comment: This is easy with `Power Query`, hold down the first three columns and right click to `Unpivot Other Columns` your job is done within seconds.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Im running excel on a Mac, not a PC. Apparently Power Query hasn't been released to its fullest extent on Mac yet.

Comment: Ok, so may I know what is your Excel Version?

Comment: 16.66.1 (22101101)

Comment: MS365 is it, I am not sure of the build version can you confirm once please

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by build version. Thats all the information I am given for version when I click on "About Microsoft Excel"

Comment: please see I have updated the `Answers` using formulas.

Comment: If you don't have powerquery why would you tag the question to powerquery?

Comment: @horseyride I didnt, nor did I tag it with Excel-formula.

Comment: My bad. Someone apparently "helped" you out. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do using **Power Query**:

[image]

---

To accomplish this task using **Power Query** please follow the steps,

• Select some cell in your **Data Table**,

• **Data Tab** => **Get&Transform** => **From Table/Range**,

• When the **PQ Editor** opens: **Home** => **Advanced Editor**,

• Make note of the **2 Tables Names**,

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

• And refer the notes

---

```
let

//Source Data Table1
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//Changed The Data Type
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ColumnA", type text}, {"ColumnB", type text}, {"ColumnC", type text}, {"ColumnD", type any}, {"ColumnE", type any}, {"Column..BM", type text}}),

//Promoted Headers, this you can exclude. Since I copied from StackOverflow, the Columns A To BM were copied
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//Unpivoted Columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Promoted Headers", {"FruitOne", "FruitTwo", "FruitThree"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Renamed the Attribute Column as Year
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "Year"}})

in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

• Importing it back into Excel press **Home** => **Close** => **Close & Load To**, when importing, you can either select **Existing Sheet** with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on **NewSheet**

[image]

---

Refer **Query Settings Panel** on right from where you can change the **Table Name** for the output, also the steps;

[image]

---

**Final Output**

[image]

---

### EDIT

> @MayukhBhattacharya Im running excel on a Mac, not a PC. Apparently
> Power Query hasn't been released to its fullest extent on Mac yet.

**Using Formulas**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `A6`

```
=INDEX($A$2:$C$3,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS($D$2:$F$3))+1,COLUMN($A$2:$C$3))
```

And Fill Down.

---

• Formula used in cell `D6`

```
=INDEX($D$1:$F$1,MOD(ROW(A1)-1,3)+1)
```

And Fill Down.

---

• Formula used in cell `E6`

```
=INDEX($D$2:$F$3,MATCH(1,(A6=$A$2:$A$3)*(B6=$B$2:$B$3)*(C6=$C$2:$C$3),0),MATCH(D6,$D$1:$F$1,0))
```

---